# Woocomerce variable product added to cart when click select option

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I enabled ajax add to cart option for my store, but for variable product when I click on select option it added to cart instead of going to product page and select attribute.
Anyone can help me to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution.
In content-product.php or other pages you want add to cart disable ajax for variable use this code:

```
<?php if ($price_html = $product->get_price_html()):?>
<?php echo $price_html;?>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<?PHP
if ($product->is_type('simple')) {?>
    <a rel="nofollow" href="<?PHP
    echo esc_url($product->add_to_cart_url());?>" data-quantity="<?PHP
    echo esc_attr(isset($quantity) ? $quantity : 1);?>" data-product_id="<?PHP
    echo esc_attr($product->id);?>" data-product_sku="<?PHP
    echo esc_attr($product->get_sku());?>" class="<?PHP
    echo esc_attr(isset($class) ? $class : 'button');?> add-to-cart ajax_add_to_cart add_to_cart_button"><?PHP
    echo esc_html($product->add_to_cart_text());?></a>
    <?PHP
} elseif ($product->is_type('variable')) {?>
    <a rel="nofollow" href="<?PHP
    echo esc_url($product->add_to_cart_url());?>" data-quantity="<?PHP
    echo esc_attr(isset($quantity) ? $quantity : 1);?>" data-product_id="<?PHP
    echo esc_attr($product->id);?>" data-product_sku="<?PHP
    echo esc_attr($product->get_sku());?>" class="<?PHP
    echo esc_attr(isset($class) ? $class : 'button ');?> add-to-cart add-to-cart-variable"><?PHP
    echo esc_html($product->add_to_cart_text());?></a>
    <?PHP
}
?>
<?php endif;?>
```